# using amsplain to list citations in abbreviated initials (but for last name) in bibliography consistently

Tags: amsplain

My BibTeX file contains citations with names in full for some and others containing names that have initials for all but the last names. I do not want to lose the full names for the citations I have. As an example, consider the following MWE that i have slightly modified from [How to order the citation by appearance using amsplain?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/663225/how-to-order-the-citation-by-appearance-using-amsplain)

```
\documentclass[abbrvbib]{article}

\begin{document}
First citation \cite{Smith1978}. Second citation \cite{yu2012}. Third citation \
cite{Heywood1988}.

\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{bibFile.bib}

\end{document}
```

The BibTeX file is as follows:

```
@article{yu2012,
  title={Extended smoothed boundary method for solving partial differential equations with general boundary conditions on complex boundaries},
  author={Yu, Hui-Chia and Chen, Hsun-Yi and Thornton, K},
  journal={Modelling and Simulation in Materials Science and Engineering},
  volume={20},
  number={7},
  pages={075008},
  year={2012},
  publisher={IOP Publishing}
}

@article{Heywood1988,
author = {Heywood, John B},
chapter = {1},
isbn = {007028637X},
journal = {Internal Combustion Engine Fundamentals},
mendeley-groups = {0paper},
pages = {1--37},
publisher = {McGraw-Hill College},
title = {{Engine Types and Their Operation}},
year = {1988}
}

@book{Smith1978,
author = {Smith, A.F. and Hales, R.},
pages = {246},
publisher = {Taylor and Francis},
title = {Werkstoff und Korrosion},
year = {1978}
}
```

Conpiling it gives me does not compress to the initials of the names that are not compressed. I tried `abbrvbib` which works for `natbib` per [Is it possible to have natbib list citations consistently?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423163/is-it-possible-to-have-natbib-list-citations-consistently), but it did not have an effect. How do I get this to work?

Switching amsplain to abbrvnat would be a solution,as below:

```
\documentclass[abbrvbib]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
First citation \cite{Smith1978}. Second citation \cite{yu2012}. Third citation \cite{Heywood1988}.

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\bibliography{bibFile.bib}

\end{document}
```

However, the journal style files at https://github.com/vtex-soft/texsupport.ims-ejpecp appears to require amsplain.

Comment: You are explicitly requesting the `amsplain` citation style with `\bibliographystyle{amsplain}`. Have you tried replacing it with `abbrvbib` instead of passing it to the document class?

Comment: Off-topic: The entry type for the entry with key `Heywood1988` should almost certainly not be `@article`. The entry type `@incollection` would appear to be far more plausible. Of course, if you decide to swith the entry type, you should also chnage the `journal` field name to `booktitle`.

Comment: You mention a bibliography style called `abbrvbib` "which works for natbib". Did you mean to write `abbrvnat` instead of `abbrvbib`?

Comment: Sorry but I meant abbrvbib, as in the referenced solution for natbib above. @epR8GaYuh switching it gets me causes BibTeX errors: I found no style file---while reading file stac.aux

Comment: The posting you've provided a link to unfortunately no longer provides a valid link to whatever document class the OP was using. For sure, the option `abbrvbib` is *not* recognized by either the `article` document class or the `natbib` citation management package.

Comment: @Mico, I have provided a MWE with the same file as above. But I need amsplain to work,  per the journal style file.